# Why can't I call this dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I defined a dictionary in the code, and am trying to take an object from it in a function I am defining.
Whenever I try to run the code it says that the dict is not callable. I even tried putting the dict in the class.

```
import random

#create dict to draw from

deck = {
    "red 1" : 1,
    "red 2" : 2,
    "red 3" : 3,
    "red 4" : 4,
    "red 5" : 5,
    "red 6" : 6
}

#adds random object from deck to hand

def draw(player):

    x = random.randint(0,6)
    player.append(deck(x))
    return player

#creates played

class status:
hand = []
name = ""
count = 1

#defines player

p1 = status()
p1.name = "Joe"

#draws card for player

draw(p1.hand)
print(p1.hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the line `player.append(deck(x))`. To retrieve an element from a dictionary, you should use square brackets `[]` and provide the key to access its value.

```
# Adds a random object from deck to hand
def draw(player):
    # Generate a random card from the deck keys
    card = random.choice(list(deck.keys()))
    player.hand.append(deck[card])
    return player
```

Answer (score 0):

draw(x) is a wrong syntax. dictionaries uses keys instead of indices.

```
import random

#create dict to draw from

deck = {
    1: "red 1",
    2: "red 2",
    3: "red 3",
    4: "red 4",
    5: "red 5",
    6: "red 6"
}

#adds random object from deck to hand

def draw(player):

    x = random.randint(0,6)
    player.append(deck[x])
    return player

#creates played

class status:
    hand = []
    name = ""
    count = 1

#defines player

p1 = status()
p1.name = "Joe"

#draws card for player

draw(p1.hand)
print(p1.hand)
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

Accessing items in a dictionary in Python uses brackets (`mydict[key]`), not parentheses (`mydict(key)`). Using parenthesis attempts to call `mydict` like a function, causing the error you are seeing.

Updating your code with this in mind gives you the following.

```py
def draw(player):
    x = random.randint(0,6)
    player.append(deck[x])
    return player
```

You can find more information on how to use dictionaries in Python below

- [Python - Access Dictionary Items](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp)
- [Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#accessing-dictionary-values)

Answer (score 0):

Just swap keys and values in your dictionary!

```py
new_dict = dict([(value, key) for key, value in deck.items()])

def draw(player):
    x = random.randint(0, 6)
    player.append(new_dict[x])
    return player
```